# Make multiple SQL into one Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server 2005 as shown below

```
DECLARE @Promotions TABLE (PromoCode VARCHAR(10),
                          DeptID VARCHAR(10),
                          VerticalID VARCHAR(10),
                          BuildingID VARCHAR(10)
                          primary key (DeptID, VerticalID, BuildingID)
                        )

INSERT INTO @Promotions VALUES ('P1_20%','101','501','1001')
INSERT INTO @Promotions VALUES ('P2_10%','101','501','All')
INSERT INTO @Promotions VALUES ('P3_5%','101','All','All')
INSERT INTO @Promotions VALUES ('P1_50%','111','606','1002')
```

We need to find out promotion code value based on the matching values in `DeptID`, `VerticalID` and `BuildingID` columns. If there is not match with these 3 columns, look for a match with the input value for `DeptID`, `VerticalID` and a default value ("All") for `BuildingID`. Still if there is no result found, look for a match by considering input `DeptID`, default value for `VerticalID` ("All") and default value for `BuildingID` ("All").

The following query works fine – however it is using a 3 part approach. Can we achieve this in a single SQL query?

**EXISTING CODE**

```
DECLARE @PromoCode VARCHAR(10)

--Part 1
SELECT @PromoCode = PromoCode
FROM @Promotions
WHERE DeptID = @inputDeptID
  AND VerticalID = @inputVerticalID
  AND BuildingID = @inputBuildingID

--Part 2
IF @PromoCode IS NULL 
BEGIN
    SELECT @PromoCode = PromoCode
    FROM @Promotions
    WHERE DeptID = @inputDeptID
      AND VerticalID = @inputVerticalID
      AND BuildingID = 'All'
END

--Part 3
IF @PromoCode IS NULL 
BEGIN
    SELECT @PromoCode = PromoCode
    FROM @Promotions
    WHERE DeptID = @inputDeptID
      AND VerticalID = 'All'
      AND BuildingID = 'All'
END

--Result
SELECT @PromoCode
```

**Testing**

```
DECLARE @inputDeptID VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @inputVerticalID VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @inputBuildingID VARCHAR(10)

SET @inputDeptID = '101'
SET @inputVerticalID = '501'
SET @inputBuildingID = '3003'
```

**Expected Result**

```
P2_10%
```

Answer (score 3):

You can approach this as a "prioritization".  That is, look for all possible matches and then choose the one that is best, using `order by` and `top`:

```
set @PromoCode = (SELECT top 1 PromoCode
                  FROM @Promotions
                  WHERE DeptID = @inputDeptID AND
                        (VerticalID = @inputVerticalID OR VerticalId = 'ALL') AND
                        (BuildingID = @inputBuildingID OR BuildingID = 'ALL')
                  ORDER BY (case when Building = 'ALL' then 1 else 0 end),
                           (case when VerticalId = 'ALL' then 1 else 0 end)
                 );
```

There are other ways to express this.  If performance is an issue and you have indexes on the columns, then a `union all` approach with `order by` may work better than `or`s in the `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not able to understand how it works. Can you please elaborate what is the relevance of `1` and `0` in the `case` statement and what is the logic behind this?

Comment: The `order by` statement is ordering the rows being returned, with exact matches at the top of the list and defaults at the bottom.  run the `select` query without the `top 1` and you will see what happens for different inputs.